# How to know that a particular line is executed?

Tags: dojo, amd

I have an Index.html that has code like below :

```
> if (configfile == 'config/all')
> 
>               {
>                   //alert ('comeconfig == ALL');
>                   //alert ('configfile ' + configfile + ' -- strpathfile : ' + strpathfile);
>                   //var temp_adji = checkfileimg_js (strpathfile);
>                   //alert (' temp ' + temp_ + ' --- pathfile : ' + strpathfile);
>                   
>                   //cek if file "*_imagery" exist ?
>                   //ImgStatus set from GetUserImageryPrivileges
>                   //checkfileimg_js : cek if file *_imagery present.
>                   if (ImgStatus && checkfileimg_js(strpathfile)) {
>                       alert (' Entrying ImgStatus && checkfileimg_js(strpathfile)');
>                       require(['viewer/Controller', configfile + '_imagery'], function(Controller, config){
>                       Controller.startup(config);
>                       });
>                       }
>                       else 
>                       {
>                       alert (' controller.startup(notauth) Hellow NOAUTH ');
>                       require(['viewer/Controller', 'config/all'], function(Controller, notauth)
>                           {
>                           alert ('Come in REQUIRE');
>                           Controller.startup(notauth);
>                           //Controller.startup(viewerv134);
>                           });
>                       }   
>               }               
>                   else    //IF configfile <> ALL (env,pims,clear dll)
>                   
>               { Some Codes }
```

How do i know that this line "Controller.startup(notauth);" is executed ? Where to check in the Chrome debugger ?

Thanks

Comment: set breack point in controller start up method   , under=> dev tool (f12) -> source -> search Controller.js -> click on it then click on the line number inside startup() function . refrech the page , the break point will stop exuction or not

Comment: I put the break point at Controller.startup.. But its just skipped, although i can find "controller(startup)" in Source -> Search. 

I put an alert inside that function (see the alert "Come in REQUIRE"), but it doesnt pop up. I also put alert on "notauth.js", it doesn't pop up too. 
On the other hand, i put the same alerts in the original sample, and they pop up. 

It seems that the line is never executed. May be the path is wrong. How do i check the parameter of the "require(['viewer/Controller', 'config/all'], function(Controller, notauth)" is correct ?

Comment: Is there an error or warning in console ?

Comment: Yes. there are some errors in the console. The console shows that it executes the wrong js file. In this line "require(['viewer/Controller', 'config/all'], function(Controller, notauth)", i define the modules to be viewer/Controller and config/all. In the folder "/config/all" there are some JS files and one of them is the "notauth.js". The Controller.JS is executed BUT It just wont execute this notauth.JS. I am very sure that the code cant find the intended JS target.

Comment: print in your post shown error

Comment: Hi Boo Berrita, Here is the screen shot of my error NOW : https://snag.gy/WkQybL.jpg. There are errors on "normal is not defined".
    
Now, The line "Controller.startup(notauth);" is propably executed. 
I can see it in the debugger window that it executes ALL.JS (Look here : https://snag.gy/9El5Ia.jpg). 
If all.js is executed, Why can't i see my alert pop up ??? I put an alert in ALL.JS. Here is my all.js : https://snag.gy/G7Fn9V.jpg

Do the "normal is not defined" error have any effects ?

Thanks for your kindness